# How to pass raw html from jsx to Api2pdf REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm trying to find the best way to pass my html table data **(React JSX)** to the api2pdf REST API https://www.api2pdf.com/

I was unable to do so, which led me to reconstruct my whole html data separately then upload it

```
const fetchReportPdf = async () => {
    await fetch("https://v2018.api2pdf.com/chrome/html", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "*Auth key placed here*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        html: `
        <html style="color: green" lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Daily Report for ${newDate}</title>
          <link
           href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
          />
        </head>
        <body>
          <div className="DailyReportTable_Container ">
            <table
              class="table table-bordered border-dark table-sm"
              style="width: 900px"
            >
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" class="text-center">
                    CIVIL WORKS FOR CONSTRUCTION OF THWAKE DAM EMBARKMENT AND
                    ASSOCIATED WORKS
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>INSPECTOR</th>
                  <td colspan="1">${report.User}</td>
                  <th>SECTION:</th>
                  <td colspan="4" style="padding-left: 10px">${
                    report.Section
                  }</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
         
        </body>
      </html>

      
      
          `,
        fileName: `${newDate} ${report.Section} ${report.Shift}.pdf`,
        options: {
          textAlign: "left",
          height: "11in",
        },
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        document.getElementById(
          "Download_Button"
        ).innerHTML = `<a className="Download_Button" href="${res.pdf}" >Download PDF</a>`;
      });
  };
```

This is the table, combined with fetched data from MongoDB which is stored in state then used in the html code above. Example is the **${report.User}**

Placing this **fetchReportPdf** function in an onClick button generates a response with a download link which i can then access and save the pdf file

Using this method has been useful so far, but now i need to map data from an array in my state.

Mapping it directly inside the html code does not work. So i tried to place a script tag and execute the code from here

```
<script type="module">
          ${function rocktripFn() {
            const rockTripArray = report.rocktrip;

            const newArr = rockTripArray.map((item, index) => {
              return `${item.Number_Of_Trips} trips made for Rock Type ${item.RockType}`;
            });

            const rocktrip = document.querySelector("#rockTripUL");
            newArr.forEach((sub) => {
              const item = document.createElement("li");
              item.innerHTML = sub;
              rocktrip.appendChild(item);
            });
          }}
          rocktripFn();
            </script>
```

**report.rocktrip** is the state holding the array that i want to map. But the pdf is blank in that section. The script only returns an output when i replace **report.rocktrip** with the actual array e.g.

```
{Number_Of_Trips: '45', RockType: '3A'},
{Number_Of_Trips: '32', RockType: '3B'}
```

But it can't map data *directly from my state*

I'm probably going about all this the wrong way when i'm certain there is a simpler way of doing this, how can i simplify this process with cleaner code?

Posting the jsx code directly from my component would definitely be ideal, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to actually use useRef hook to obtain the innerHTML of the targeted div.

```
import useRef from "react";
const reportRef = useRef();

const fetchReportPdf = async () => {
    const reportHTML = reportRef.current.innerHTML;
    await fetch("https://v2018.api2pdf.com/chrome/html", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Auth key placed here",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        html: `
        <html style="color: green" lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Daily Report for ${newDate}</title>
         
          <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
          />
        </head>
        <body>
        <div className="DailyReportTable_Container ">
        ${reportHTML}
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>

      
      
          `,
        fileName: `${newDate} ${report.Section} ${report.Shift}.pdf`,
        options: {
          textAlign: "left",
          height: "11in",
        },
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        document.getElementById(
          "Download_Button"
        ).innerHTML = `<a className="Download_Button" href="${res.pdf}" >Download PDF</a>`;
      });
  };

<table className="table-responsive" ref={reportRef}>
```